# Change background color of every other row

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I'm trying to replicate the default settings of `ag-grid` which paints every other rows background in a slightly different color. But when I try to reorder columns clicking on `headerColumn` the background colors doesn't reorder.

This is my current approach that isn´t working

```js
cellStyle(params) {
  let backgroundColor = #FFFFFF;
  if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 1) backgroundColor = #E04F00;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/bHLEmECLNby3obIT, this example shows the desired behavior.

Is there a way to acces and change those default colors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out that the default themes of `ag-grid` already did what I wanted, the thing is that the theme I'm using has two colors that are very similar, what I really needed was to change that default color.

I was able to achieve that by overriding theme's variable

```css
.ag-theme-balham {
  --ag-odd-row-background-color: #E04F00;
}
.ag-theme-balham .ag-row-odd {
  background-color: var(--ag-odd-row-background-color);
}
```

I followed their documentation, first here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/, that took me to https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-customise-theme, where I discovered which variable I should edit.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is going to be the easiest solution to this. I don't see your html, but essentially you will want to reference the html table's rows, and then add a css `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` to them. Here is an example:

```css
p:nth-child(odd)
{
    background: #ccc;
}
p:nth-child(even)
{
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

And [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd) are some more examples from w3:

Depending on what your specific code looks like, there may be different ways of doing this. I noticed you have js in your question, but since there was the css tag, I gave a css answer.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the working example you are showing here, each `.ag-row` div has an additional class `.ag-row-odd` or `.ag-row-even`. So basically those classes mimic the behavior you could achieve by using `.ag-row:nth-child(odd)` and `.ag-row:nth-child(even)`.

What might be happening in this case is that when you reorder the `.ag-row` elements the classes are not being updated, instead just moved around. What that would represent is something like this:

```html
<!-- Default //-->
<div class="ag-row ag-row-even"></div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-odd"></div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-even"></div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-odd"></div>

<!-- Sorted //-->
<div class="ag-row ag-row-odd"></div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-odd"></div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-even"></div>
<div class="ag-row ag-row-odd"></div>
```

So in this case what I would recommend is either to change the styles to:

```css
.ag-row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.ag-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

If that's not an option than you should review the script that reorders the `.ag-row` elements as it's probably not changing the classes accordingly.

**UPDATE**

I think I found your issue. I checked [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php)

And while inspecting elements I saw that when you reorder, each row has these two attributes.

```html
<div row-index="3" aria-rowindex="7"></div>
```

From what I was able to determine even if you change your sort parameters, those two attributes don't actually change. So if you base your row styles on them, like you do with the row-index parameter, you'll never get a correct order, because sometimes you get:

```html
<div row-index="3" aria-rowindex="7"></div>
<div row-index="5" aria-rowindex="9"></div>
<div row-index="7" aria-rowindex="11"></div>
```

As this is not incorrect, the styles are applied, but not in the order you would prefer. The script is doing its job as intended, it's just that your condition for the colors is not working.

The solution to this I think would be 100% css and for you to remove the `cellStyle` definition, because I think the problem lies there.

Comment: this worked for first render but not after reordering, guess I'll need to check reorder script somewhere =(

Comment: Hello @BernardoMarques if you provide a working online example I might be able to help more by checking what your script does.

Comment: Hello @BernardoMarques I updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: Yeah, I think the easiest way is going to be costumizing their themes. I found this https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-customise-theme, on their README it says that when you change something you can see it reflected on your styles.scss but I'm new to scss I can´t see any change

Comment: Normally for scss there should be a process that compiles de SCSS files to make resulting CSS files, so you might need to setup the compilation process. Other than that, you should check the already defined styles for ag-grid.